# Setting a default value for a dynamic cascading validation list in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, data-validation

I have finally figured out how to build a dynamic cascading set of lists in Excel using Data Validation and the INDIRECT function.  However, I'm running into a problem.

I would like to set up my spreadsheet so that whenever a change is made in a data validation list, all subsequent lists are set to a default value.  For example:

Let's say I have List1, List2, List3, and List4.  Each list's values are dependent on the selection made in the list before it.  When I start the spreadsheet, I want all lists to default to "ALL".  When the user selects a value in List1, List2 updates with a set of valid choices.  I'd like to default List2 to one of those choices.  However, while I can get List2 to populate with the correct set of selection options, I cannot get my desired default value assigned to it.

Similarly, if the user makes a selection in List1, List2, and List3, then goes back and changes List1, I'd like List2-List4 to default back to "ALL".

How do I do this?

Comment: This a job for a VBA worksheet_change event trigger.  I don't have time right now to give the details (later I will if you still need help), but that's where you should direct your research.

Comment: You have probably solved this by now or given up. I agree with Excellll that a worksheet change event might be the easiest. However, with the List option for Data Validation, the source can be an expression such as `=IF(A1="List1",C1:C5,D1:D4)`. I have tested this with the value of cell A1 selected from a list and it does work in the way you seek.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem?

Comment: FYI, a nonVBA method I employ for this problem is to apply a CONDITIONAL formatting to the subsequent cells that checks if the current value it holds matches a value in the current INDIRECT() ref range.  If NOT, then the cell turns red, or the value disappears (matching font/background) so the user knows the value for that cell must be updated/reselected.

Comment: To illustrate both the VBA method and the CF method I mentioned above, there is a [sample file here](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/system/app/pages/search?scope=search-site&q=dependent) _DependentLists3.xls_

Comment: @JerryBeaucaire: Could you post that as an answer? Or doesn't it fully answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

A nonVBA method I employ for this problem is to apply a CONDITIONAL formatting to the subsequent cells that checks if the current value it holds matches a value in the current INDIRECT() ref range. If NOT, then the cell turns red, or the value disappears (matching font/background) so the user knows the value for that cell must be updated/reselected.

To illustrate this (and the VBA method mentioned by others above), there is a [sample file here](http://sites.madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/).  The file you want is *DependentLists3.xls*